# How to get the default syle of my Button in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have create a Button style under Resource folder of the main application. I have added the reference of this button syle in the App.xml of the main application.

Now this style is applicable to all the buttons in the main application or any other assembly.

I want if I want to override my custom style of button to the normal button style , what should I do ??

Please help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't want your custom style to be applied in Button just set *Style={x:Null}*.